# Submitting Query for PHP/mySQL - Query Failed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to submit my query into mySQL database but it keeps stating that it fails. It connects to the database fine but will not integrate the query into the table called 'ticket'.

```
 <?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  include 'mysqli_connect.php';

  $query = "INSERT INTO ticket (Ticket_ID, Submit_Date, F_Name, 
  L_Name, Email, Ph_Num, Subject, Priority, Description)
  VALUES ('$_POST[Ticket_ID]', '$_POST[Submit_Date]', 
  '$_POST[F_Name]', '$_POST[L_Name]', '$_POST[Email]', 
  '$_POST[Ph_Num]', '$_POST[Subject]', '$_POST[Priority]', 
  '$_POST[Description]')";

  $result = mysqli_query($query) or die ('Query Failed:' . 
  mysqli_error());
  mysql_close($conn);
  } else {
  echo "No submit";
  }

  ?>
```

Outputs:
Connected Database SuccessfullyQuery Failed:

Comment: `mysqli_query($connection,$query)`;

Comment: Yeah, you're missing a lot here. 1. `mysql_*` doesn't mix with `mysqli_*` - apples and oranges, different fruits. 2. The first argument to most `mysqli_*` function, is the connection object (see the manual of each function! http://php.net/mysqli.query). 3) You should use parameterized queries with placeholders (http://php.net/mysqli.prepare)

Comment: Do you have access to the MySQL logs? Are you logging query errors?

Have you tried your query with dummy data you set directly in variables?

More info needed.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` I'll just leave this here, so you can get the actual errors next time ;-) Helps a lot more than wildly guessing.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query()` has 2 parameters, first is the variable connection, and second is variable of query...
so I think it could be

```
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ('Query Failed:' .mysqli_error($conn));
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this

```
 <?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  include 'mysqli_connect.php';

  $query = "INSERT INTO ticket (Ticket_ID, Submit_Date, F_Name, 
  L_Name, Email, Ph_Num, Subject, Priority, Description)
  VALUES ('".$_POST['Ticket_ID']."', '".$_POST['Submit_Date']."', 
  '".$_POST['F_Name']."', '".$_POST['L_Name']."', '".$_POST['Email']."', 
  '".$_POST['Ph_Num']."', '".$_POST['Subject']."', '".$_POST['Priority']."', 
  '".$_POST['Description']."')";

  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die ('Query Failed:' . 
  mysqli_error($conn));
  mysqli_close($conn);
  } else {
  echo "No submit";
  }

  ?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_error()` won't give you anything without an argument, `mysql_close()` doesn't belong there either ;-) Wrong API.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ticket (Ticket_ID, Submit_Date, F_Name, 
  L_Name, Email, Ph_Num, Subject, Priority, Description)
  VALUES ('{$_POST['Ticket_ID']}', '{$_POST['Submit_Date']}', 
  '{$_POST['F_Name']}', '{$_POST['L_Name']}', '{$_POST['Email']}', 
  '{$_POST['Ph_Num']}', '{$_POST['Subject']}', '{$_POST['Priority']}', 
  '{$_POST['Description']}')";
```

and replace `mysqli_query($query), mysqli_error(), mysql_close($conn)` with

```
mysqli_query($conn, $query), mysqli_error($conn),  mysqli_close($conn)
```